# Dependencies in bound OpenGL objects

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

If I understand it correctly, some of the OpenGL states are dependent on other states:

```
glUseProgram(program1);
glUniform1i(program1Uniform1, x);
glUseProgram(program2);
glUniform1i(program2Uniform1, y);
glUseProgram(program1);
```

At the end of this code snippet, the uniform of `program1` is still set to `x`, even if `program1Uniform1` has the same index as `program2Uniform1`. So, the second call to `glUniform1i` does not overwrite the first call, because we have switched the shader program between the two calls.

**Is that correct so far?**

If it is correct, then the *uniform state* has some kind of dependency on the *program state*, because if we switch the program by calling `glUseProgram()`, the *uniform state* is changed implicitly.

**Is there a book or a website where those dependencies are listed?**

I think I understand the concepts of shader programs, FBOs, VBOs, VAOs, uniforms, attributes, etc., but I still have difficulties putting them together. I always end up asking myself "do I have to switch state B after switching state A, or is state B dependent on state A?"

Comment: The [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page) is a pretty reliable resource. It doesn't have an explicit list in any place (as such a list would be pretty gigantic), but each of those objects has a page dedicated to it, where all of its functions are discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that correct so far?

Yes, it is.

> If it is correct, then the uniform state has some kind of dependency
>   on the program state, because if we switch the program by calling
>   glUseProgram(), the uniform state is changed implicitly.

Well, conceptually it isn't so much that the uniform state is dependent on the program state, but the uniform state is *part* of the program state. There is no independent uniform state that gets magically switched when the program switches, only the uniform values of the individual programs (with those of the currently active program being accessible through the API).

> Is there a book or a website where those dependencies are listed?

Well, your favourite OpenGL tutorial or book should have told you thoroughly about the individual object types, what state they encapsulate and how they interact with each other. Other than that, the [OpenGL sepcification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/) has the last word, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that correct so far?

Yes. Uniforrms are **per program state**.

> if we switch the program by calling glUseProgram(), the uniform state is changed implicitly.

Well, not really. As the uniforms are per program state, no uniform state is chnaged at all. Just the current program has changed.

> Is there a book or a website where those dependencies are listed?

The definitive source for such things is the [OpenGL Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf), have especially a look in Chapter 23 "State Tables".